# Angular js App minification

Tags: angularjs, bundling-and-minification

Very popular issue:

> Unknown provider: nProvider <- n <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view
>   <- $state

I use MVC Bundling for this.

How to read this message?

Does it mean that `$state` requires `$view` that requires `$templateFactory` etc.?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: more code required to solve your problem

Comment: Actually I managed to find the problem. 
I have added all scripts to index.html. And then start to minificate them with MVC bundle part by part. After this I have found the incorrect for minification script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem in some external directives. So I go through all of them and fixed syntax of service injections:

from

```
app.service('myService', function($scope, $animate) {});
```

to

```
app.service('myService', ['$scope', '$animate', function($scope, $animate) {}]);
```

To understand where is the problem
I have added all scripts to index.html. And then start to minificate scripts with MVC bundle part by part. After this I have found the incorrect for minification script.