# angular.module config using min.js files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to configure my angular module like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', []).config(function ($sceDelegateProvider) {
   $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
      ...
   ]);
});
```

But when I minify the js file the `$sceDelegateProvider` parameter is being convert to shorter name.

I didnt find a way to pass the parameter name as a string. (like it is in the module constructor)

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular js App minification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341645/angular-js-app-minification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing a function into config, pass an array where the first variables are the parameter names as string and the last one is the function:

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', []).config(['$sceDelegateProvider' , function ($sceDelegateProvider) {
   $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
      ...
   ]);
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought it will be so simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `$sceDelegateProvider` as a dependency in your config:

```
<your-module>.config(['$sceDelegateProvider', function($sceDelegateProvider){}]);
```

Then angular will inject `$sceDelegateProvider` to your config function mapping it to the parameter regardless of the parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
angular.module('myModule', []) 
    .config(['depProvider', function(depProvider) { 
        // ...     
      }])
```

See here for more details

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di